# Full calendar Mobile view

Tags: fullcalendar

How can I resize Fullcalendar on mobile? I want to display agendaWeek on desktop and tablet, however in mobile, I want display agendaDay. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used [eventAfterAllRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventAfterAllRender). The function will handle the checking if the user uses a mobile device, it is a mobile device then it will simply change the calendar view from the default `agendaWeek` into `agendaDay` using the [changeView](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/changeView) method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
      },
      defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
      defaultDate: '2018-03-12',
      events: [
      {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2018-03-01',
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2018-03-07',
        end: '2018-03-10'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2018-03-09T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2018-03-16T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Conference',
        start: '2018-03-11',
        end: '2018-03-13'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2018-03-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2018-03-12T12:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2018-03-12T12:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2018-03-12T14:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Happy Hour',
        start: '2018-03-12T17:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Dinner',
        start: '2018-03-12T20:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2018-03-13T07:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2018-03-28'
      }
      ],
      eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
        if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
        } //IF MOBILE CHANGE VIEW TO AGENDA DAY
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.css'>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: thank you very much. I've done it. I have to learn more :(